# Range.Find() fails

Tags: vba, excel

I have a requirement which goes like this:

- I have two Excel files with data from Columns A to Q
- I iterate through each row in each sheet of one Excel, get the values in column A, and find them in the other Excel for the corresponding sheet.
- If there is a match, I check the values in Column A, G and J match in both Excel. If they don't match they are logged in a Log File (Excel with matrix type representation of where the mismatch is). (Yet to be Implemented)
- If there is no match, I have to log them again. (Yet to be Implemented)

The Code is:

```
For Each workSheet1 In MainWorkBook.Worksheets
Set MainWorksheet = workSheet1
Set SecondaryWorksheet = workSheet1
MainWorksheet.Activate
Cells.Select
Selection.EntireColumn.Hidden = False
Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = False
rowcount = MainWorksheet.Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
For i = 3 To rowcount
    MainCheckName = Trim(MainWorksheet.Cells(i, "A"))
    If (PreviousCheck <> MainCheckName And MainCheckName <> "") Then
        SecondaryWorksheet.Activate
        rowcount = SecondaryWorksheet.Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        SecondaryWorksheet.Range(SecondaryWorksheet.Cells(1, "A"), SecondaryWorksheet.Cells(rowcount, "A")).Select
        Set SecondaryCheckName = Selection.Find(what:=MainCheckName, LookAt:=xlWhole)
        If Not SecondaryCheckName Is Nothing Then
            CheckRow = Selection.Find(what:=MainCheckName, LookAt:=xlWhole).Row
                <further process here>

Next Next
```

Now, I have a problem with this line:

```
Set SecondaryCheckName = Selection.Find(what:=MainCheckName, LookAt:=xlWhole)
```

After processing this activity for some ten sheets, though I have the contents which match in both the worksheets of different workbooks, I get `Nothing` returned for the `Find` function.

What is wrong and why is the condition failing here?

Comment: I see you have 2 `For`s but only one next

Comment: Oops, forgot to add that `Next` in code

Comment: `MainWorksheet` and `SecondaryWorksheet` are set to the same worksheet during  each iteration of the outside `For .. Each ... Next`. How can there be any difference?

Comment: Hi Jeeped, I have the same worksheet in both the workbooks. Hence the similar sheet names

Comment: You haven't determined what workbook the worksheets are from`Set MainWorksheet = workSheet1`
`Set SecondaryWorksheet = workSheet1` are both the same sheets in `MainWorkBook`

Comment: That should be `Set SecondaryWorksheet = SecondaryWorkbook.sheets(workSheet1.name)` only that there is no `SecondaryWorkbook` defined in the code shown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have not included the declarations for `SecondaryCheckName`, but every indication is that it is a string not a Range type variable. You should not `Set` it to the [Range object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838238.aspx) returned by the [Range.Find method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839746.aspx); it should be simply assigned to the .Find result's value. Alternately, declare it as a Range type variable so you can `Set` it to a Range Object for future use.

```
SecondaryCheckName = Selection.Find(what:=MainCheckName, LookAt:=xlWhole).Value2
```

That;s the answer to why you are receiving the error. However, I don't think this is the best way of accomplishing your goal. There is a decided lack of error control and you should reduce if not completely avoid the use of .Select`and`Selection`.

Comment: Thanks a ton Jeeped. Yes the error Control techniques are yet to be placed but preparing the skeleton first.

Comment: Why 'not Set it to the Range object' while the example on MSDN does use the set keyword?